# select event not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I try to store an identifier into an hiddenfield when a value is selected with a jquery autocomplete field.

But the select event is never fired and I dont't see why..

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').autocomplete(
    {
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Controller/Method", type: "POST", dataType: "json",                    
                data: { Comparaison: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {                            
                        return { label: item.text, value: item.text, id : item.value };
                    }));
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {                        
                    alert("selected");
                    //$("#idProprio").val(ui.item.id);
                }
            });
        },
    });
});
```

The autocompletion is properly working, I can see the values, select one but when I select a value nothig happens..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your curly braces are wrong. `select` is being set as part of the ajax parameter, not autocomplete:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test').autocomplete(
    {
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Controller/Method", type: "POST", dataType: "json",                    
                data: { Comparaison: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {                            
                        return { label: item.text, value: item.text, id : item.value };
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {                        
            alert("selected");
            //$("#idProprio").val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
});
```